# JTable RowFilter displays wrong rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I'm using custom class extending RowFilter to filter my table based on the boolean value in the column

```
public class MyRowFilter extends RowFilter<Object, Integer> {

    @Override
    public boolean include(Entry entry) {

        return (boolean) entry.getValue(0));
    }
}
```

I assign it to table as such

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter();
myRowFilter = new MyRowFilter(myTableModel);
tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(myRowFilter);
myTable.setRowSorter(platformTableRowSorter);
```

But what i get on the form is just first N (amount of time include() returned true) rows of myTable instead of the ones for which include() returned true.

What can cause such behavior?

Comment: Are you sure your values are not in correct order? When ordering numbers that are Strings, the strings would be ordered alphapatically, not asceding numbering

Comment: @Desolator their order is correct, what wrong is rows what are being displayed - only one of them matches the filter.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for JTable, XxxTableModel in local variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
String table_event = table_job.getModel().getValueAt(table_job.
                          convertRowIndexToModel(row), 0).toString());
```

Comment: Thank you! Turns out i messed up row indexes in rendering.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class JTableFilterDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] data = { { "A", 5 }, { "B", 2 }, { "C", 4 }, { "D", 8 } };
    String columnNames[] = { "Item", "Value" };
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
      }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(model);

    RowFilter<Object, Object> filter = new RowFilter<Object, Object>() {
      public boolean include(Entry entry) {
        Integer population = (Integer) entry.getValue(1);
        return population.intValue() > 3;
      }
    };

    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Filtering Table");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

See this code